# what is System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage and how does my View files inherit from it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `UrlHelper` to generate URLs on my Views and Controllers and noticed that the `UrlHelper` property(named `Url`) is called from 2 different abstract classes in each cases.

Views: From System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage[from metadata]

Controllers: From System.Web.Mvc.Controllers[from metadata]

//Both in the namespace of System.Web.Mvc

I was wondering where these classes are stored and how my views and controllers inherit from these.

The question came up as I was attempting to instantiate a `UrlHelper` object in my ViewModels project and I could not get it to do so without specifically declaring a new instance of the `UrlHelper` class, whereas I could instantiate `UrlHelper` objects with the default get; set; properties in the respective abstract classes for both my views and controllers.

All of the files in which I'm calling the `UrlHelper` references System.Web.Mvc

Thanks!

Comment: XY problem. Why do you need an UrlHelper in your viewmodels? And how is the answer to these questions going to help with that? _How_ do your controllers inherit from Controller? You do that, in your code. How do views inherit from WebViewPage? By convention. No what are you going to do?

Comment: Those classes are stored in the `System.Web.Mvc.dll` assembly.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear as to what the situation I'm in. I just started my coop and I'm thrown at a web app built by previous coop students. Currently it uses UrlHelper in the View files to generate Urls to navigate to different pages of the app and links to subsequent pages within a page(ex. details view and edit view) are generated using various concatenations of different properties within the viewmodels. This is causing a problem within VPN setting because the UrlHelper generated URLs work fine but the concatenated URLs do not. So I was trying to call the UrlHelper properties on viewmodels.

Comment: @JAKE Edit your question and share the code with us what isn't working correctly.